# Disabling scrolling on POST

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, css

I have a page that uses a POST to retrieve data from mySQL. However, it's irritating because if I scroll down and click something that does a POST, it kicks the page all the way back up to top. Anyone know of some javascript/jquery plugin that can fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you do an AJAX POST and replace the page's contents with that which results from the AJAX POST, this scrolling effect will not be a problem.

Keep in mind that this operation might appear seamless for the user (no browser loading).

Let's say you have a form:

```
<form id="some_form" action="myphp.php">
    <input name="something" value="foo"/>
    <input name="something_else" value="bar" /> 
</form>
```

and jQuery:

```
$("#some_form").submit(function() {
   var url = $(this).attr("action");
   var form_data = $(this).serialize();
   // post the same data via an AJAX call
   $.post(url, form_data, function(data) {
      // replace the contents from the received response
      $("html").html(data);
   });
   // disable the default form submit behavior
   return false;
});
```

Comment: Works only with javascript enabled.

Comment: @uku: Any help on how do do that?

Comment: @hakre seeing as the question is tagged [tag:javascript] you'd suspect he has javascript enabled.

Answer (score 1):

did you try [Jumping Inside Pages](http://www.myhtmltutorials.com/jump.html) ?

and another example [How To Link to a Specific Spot on a Page](http://www.webweaver.nu/html-tips/link-within-a-page.shtml)

```
<div id="whatever-you-want-to-call-it">
    The content of your div here.
</div>
```

and the url to get to that point

```
http://www.pagename.html#whatever-you-want-to-call-it
```

Comment: was looking for more of a dynamic way of doing it.. otherwise I'd have to implement this into every single list item I have that's being pulled from the server..

Comment: @Zakman411: Create those anchors dynamically as well when you render the list.

Answer (score 0):

It's more clear to use the e.preventDefault(); with jQuery (like Uku Loskit suggested).
There is also a mistake in his code (it won't work) so I fixed it.

Here is his code with the change:

```
<form id="some_form" action="myphp.php"">
    <input name="something" value="foo"/>
    <input name="something_else" value="bar" /> 
</form>
```

and jQuery:

```
$("#some_form").submit(function(e) { // e = event object, it has many usefull properties and methods
   e.preventDefault();
   var url = $(this).attr("action");
   var form_data = $(this).serialize();
   // post the same data via an AJAX call
   $.post(url, form_data, function(data) {
      // replace the contents from the received response
      $(document).html(data);
   });
});
```

By the way, there is no way how to achieve that without javascript if you want to stay at the same page (dont reload, dont change url). If it is used like pagination, then you could add #some-id after the url and then add the id 'some-id' to item which should be at the top when page loads. This will work well - no js needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `scrollTop`:

```
$("#some_form").submit(function() {
   var url = $(this).attr("action");
   var form_data = $(this).serialize();
   var currentScrollTop = $('body').scrollTop();

   // post the data via an AJAX call
   $.post(url, form_data, function(data) {
      // replace the contents from the received response
      $(document).html(data);
      $('body').scrollTop(currentScrollTop);
   });

   // disable the default form submit behavior
   return false;
});
```